# Upload File using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file but unable to upload. It shows flg value 2. Can some one describe the problem.

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$file_name = $file['name'];
$file_size = $file['size'];
$file_error = $file['error'];
$file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
$file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
$file_destination = 'upload/' . $title .'.' . $file_ext;
if($file_size < 2097152){
  if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
    $flg = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    $flg = 2;
  }
}
else
{
  $flg = 3;
}
```

Comment: If failed: So... http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use document_root to get absolute path like this:

```
$file_destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/" . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $file_destination);
```